# Sum and Count of Non-Zero Consecutive Values in a Dataframe Column

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series

I have a dataframe in the following format:

```
timestamp,          value
2019-05-03 20:19:19,    0.0
2019-05-03 20:19:20,    5.1
2019-05-03 20:19:21,    5.2
2019-05-03 20:19:22,    4.8
2019-05-03 20:19:23,    0.0
2019-05-03 20:19:24,    0.0
2019-05-03 20:19:25,    8.7
2019-05-03 20:19:26,    9.3
2019-05-03 20:19:27,    2.2
2019-05-03 20:19:28,    0.0
2019-05-03 20:19:29,    0.0
2019-05-03 20:19:30,    0.0
2019-05-03 20:19:31,    2.9
2019-05-03 20:19:32,    2.2
2019-05-03 20:19:33,    0.0
2019-05-03 20:19:34,    0.0
```

and so on

My goal is to extract consecutive non-zero values (events) and then find sum, average and count for each of the groups

I want the output to be in the following format:

```
[
    [15.1,5.033,3], 
    [20.2,6.73,3],
    [5.1,2.55,2], 
    and so on
]
```

Each row will have 3 numbers for each event. The first number is sum of numbers in the event, third number is count of numbers in the the event and second number is average. I tried searching for a solution on SO but couldn't find one. Also I am concerned about time efficiency too because I am doing this on a large data-frame.

This is the general outline of the code that I have so far:

```py
events_matrix = []
current_event = []
def collect_events(self, row):
    time, value = row[0], row[1]
    if value > 0.0:
        current_event.append([time, value])
    elif value == 0.0:
       events_matrix.append(current_event)
        current_event = []


data.apply(lambda x: self.collect_events(x), axis=1)


for index, event in enumerate(events_matrix):
    duration = np.size(event, axis=0)
    total_sum = np.sum(np.array(event)[:, 1].astype(np.float), axis=0)
    average = (total_sum/duration)
    flow_and_duration.append([total_sum, average, duration])
```

Problem is that this code is very slow for my purposes. Thanks for the help

Comment: could you please show what have you tried so far? In that way it'll be easier for others to help you. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please post an output example accurate to the example you posted of the data, also provide us with what you tried so far

Comment: modified original question based on suggestions

Answer (score -1):

Just to give you help as a hint:

```
print(df.groupby("value")['value'].count())
print(df.groupby("value")['value'].mean())
print(df.groupby("value")['value'].sum())
```

Try using groupby and its follow functions.

Sorry it's just that your question wasn't too clear with no work provided.